# Как импортировать структуру БД Mysql без импорта данных?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как импортировать только структуру БД Mysql, а не сами данные, чтобы с чистого листа заполнять? Покажите, где про это почитать, если в двух словах не сказать. Спасибо.

Comment: а чем плохо импортировать с данными которые потом очистить ?

Comment: а если их там 50тб?

Comment: <pre><code>show create table 'tablename'?</code></pre>

Comment: А через phpMyAdmin разве нельзя? Там при экспорте есть параметры: или структура, или данные, или структура и данные

Comment: Если через консольный mysqldump то с ключом `--no-data` получится резервная копия только структуры.

Comment: В дополнение к коменту @KiTE - [почитайте подбробнее об этому](http://citforum.ru/database/mysqldoc/mysqldoc_02.shtml#7)

Comment: Хорошая мысль - вместе с данными, а как потом их удалить из некоторых таблиц, подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

Импортируйте в месте с данными, а потом, при экспорте через phpmyadmin посмотрите на пунктик "Сохранение таблицы" в подразделе "Параметры формата".

Answer (score 1):

Можно через консоль создать структуру базы без данных:

```
mysqldump --no-data - u USER -p DATABASE > /path/to/file/dump.sql
```

а потом уже залить:

```
mysql -u USER -p DATABASE < /path/to/dump.sql
```